# MongoDB Warning impossible to clear

Tags: mongodb, configuration, installation, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and MongoDB 4.0.1. When I use mongo shell I got this :

```
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

So I read lot of threads about this problem but nothing works... I created my users as it said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat) and login with my created users but I got again the same warnings.

I don't have created the data/db folder. I don't know if it's necessary in 4.0.1 version. It's confused for me. Inside my `mongod.conf` I got this :

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
```

Should I let this config or should I rename to :

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
```

I don't know what to do. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you enabled authentication in your config file and restarted mongodb server? Also is /var/lib/mongodb is mounted on XFS based partition?

Comment: Yes I just remember to enable security authentication in the config file. But I don't understand why people don't mention to do this. It's so important... I'm becoming mad. So I don't have any warning now it works. But I don't understand why XFS warning is gone ? O_o

Comment: let me know if your problem is resolved. If not then please share your config file and the output of `df -h` command

Comment: It's resolved. But can you tell me if it's necessary to change my dbpath and create the  /data/db folders ?

Comment: I don't feel it is needed.

Comment: Both of these messages are warnings, not errors. See [Ask Ubuntu: warnings after upgrading from MongoDB 2.6 to 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/a/895168/247583) for an answer addressing the same question. If this is a development system that is only accessible locally you can choose to ignore the warnings. For a production environment you would certainly want to resolve these.